# Most efficient way to farm festive drinks

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am working on the Festive achievements this year and I am noticed that the [Festive Imbiber achievement](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/A_Very_Merry_Wintersday_(2015_achievements)) requires you to drink 10,000 festive drinks.

That's a very large number of drinks! I figured with trading post prices of the required items gradually increasing, but gifts having an 80% chance of dropping a drink, it would be more productive to farm gifts to get my drinks, rather than buying them.

So which festive activities will yield the largest number of gifts for the time spent? And is farming gifts the best approach to unlocking this achievement?

During my time getting the other achievements I managed to amass 277 drinks. Which involved 3 rounds of Bell Choir, 4 rounds of Snowball Blitz, 3 rounds of 
Toypocalypse and a frustrating number of jumping puzzle attempts.

The drinks in question are,

- Cup of Spiced Apple Cider
- Glass of Buttered Spirits
- Mug of Eggnog
- Snowman Tonic
- Reindeer Tonic
- Festive Golem Tonic

Further reading:
[Wintersday 2015 Dulfy.net](http://dulfy.net/2015/12/15/gw2-wintersday-2015-coverage-guide/)
[Festive Imbiber achievement will run beyond Jan 12th](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/Updates-about-Wintersday)

Comment: I'm very interested in the answer to this, since the drinks are also a great source of income for players not going for the achievement (and the shoulders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're good at the [Winter Wonderland](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Winter_Wonderland) jumping puzzle, you can get 10 [gifts](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Wintersday_Gift) every 2-3 minutes.

You can also purchase gifts from the [Wintersday Vendor](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Charity_Corps_Seraph) for [karma](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Karma). The first 10 you buy each day will only cost 700 karma, but the price will increase for every 10 until it reaches 3,850 karma and one [flawless snowflake](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Flawless_Snowflake) per gift. I recommend buying out the first few tiers each day if you have extra karma.

Once you've stocked up on gifts, open your gifts for drinks and sell what you don't want. Keep in mind that many of the consumables from the gifts will give +10% karma nourishments, which can help you afford more gifts.

Comment: Note that there are ways to turn karma into gold, and there comes a point where karma -> gold -> drinks on TP (around 8s) is more efficient than buying presents for karma directly.

Comment: @MrLemon The usual most efficient karma to gold conversion is to put 4 gloves into the mystic forge, and salvage it into linen. That's (266 karma * 4) / 1.5 (linen scraps per salvage) = 709.3 karma per linen scrap. Linen scraps are currently going for 5.25s on the TP, which nets 4.46s after tax. That's 6.29s per 1000 karma. The cheapest drink is 7.07s now, that's 1124 karma per drink. The average gift gives ~0.8 drinks per gift and includes a few silver worth of items to sell (or work on the candy cane achievement at the same time). So the first few tiers of buying gifts are more profitable.

Comment: @MrLemon Also, buying and converting gloves in the mystic forge takes a significant amount of time, while clicking "Buy" 10-40 times at the Wintersday Vendor only takes a few seconds. I should note that the linen conversion doesn't have any daily limits like purchasing gifts does, though.